# Firebase - Sign up - new name if not exist

Tags: android, database, firebase, kotlin

I need help registering a new user on Firebase, I wish that if the name is already taken, it will return a Toast message asking to choose another name.

How can I do it?

[image: Its my Database]

```
private fun signUp(view: View, name: String, mail: String, pass: String) {
    signUp.visibility = View.GONE
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pass)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                userData.session = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.remember).isChecked
                val user = auth.currentUser
                database.getReference("User Index").child(user!!.uid).setValue(name)
                myRef.child(user.uid).child("Followers").setValue(0)
                myRef.child(user.uid).child("Following").setValue(0)
                myRef.child(user.uid).child("Email").setValue(mail)
                myRef.child(user.uid).child("Name").setValue(name)
                myRef.child(user.uid).child("Bio").setValue("Ma Bio personnel")
                userData.name = name
                userData.email = mail
                userData.uid = user.uid
                userData.image = ConstantConfig().image
                myRef.child(user.uid).child("Photo").setValue(ConstantConfig().image)
                startActivity(Intent(this, PhotoAccountActivity::class.java))
                finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would like to know if a username has already been taken or not however, I would advice against it as if you know a username has been taken you know that username is a valid entry inside of the database and therefore, a hacker only needs the password not the password and username. So from a security stand point it is not a good idea.

If you want to know anyway I would probe the database  try fetching the username inside of the username database and if it returns true it exists and you will need to register with a different username.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this reference code and modify it with yours :

```
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

ref.child("rooms/room1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists(){
        print("true rooms exist")
    }else{
        print("false room doesn't exist")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Demanding unique names is likely problematic (two people can certainly have the same name; are you going to make one of them lie?), so let's assume you mean a user handle (like a twitter handle for example) and not a person name.

Since the handle is unique, a simple answer is to simply key the data by the unique handle:

```
/users/<user handle>/ {uid: "<auth uid here>"}
```

Now it's guaranteed to be unique. Your security rule will say something like:

```
"users": {
   "$handle": {
      // I can only write to my own user record
      ".write": "data.child('uid') == auth.uid || !data.exists() && newData.hasChild('uid')",
      "uid": {
         // I can only write my own uid
         ".validate": "!data.exists() && newData.val() == auth.uid"
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to get more sophisticated, you can [set a claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) on the auth token and use that to verify who owns a given handle:

```
"users": {
   "$handle": {
      ".write": "auth.token.handle == $handle && (data.hasChild('uid') || newData.hasChild('uid'))",
      "uid": {
         // I can only write my own uid
         ".validate": "newData.val() == auth.uid"
      }
   }
}
```

If you are using real names then they aren't suitable for keys (they can contain illegal characters like `.`) so you would need to sanitize them to remove special [disallowed characters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree).

Note that you could also do this with an index if you want to keep records keyed by uid. So something like this:

```
/usernames/<sanitized user name>/<uid>
```

You can check for an existing name as follows:

```
firebase.database().ref("/usernames/<sanatized name>").once('value')
    .then(snap => console.log("username " + (snap.exists()? "exists" : "does not exist")));
```

And you would use validation and an index like the following:

```
"users": {
   "$userId": {
      "name": {
         // I can only have a name in my profile if I've already claimed it
         ".validate": "root.child('usernames/' + sanitizeUserName(data.val())).val() == auth.uid"
      }
   }
}

"usernames": {
    "$name": {
       // I can't overwrite an existing claim on this name
       // I can only set it to my own id
       ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```